# jquery mobile - MVC: How to save input from popup dialogs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Newbie here, scratching my head on this one.

How do you normally save information specified in a popup dialog for use by other forms on your page?

Scenaro:

1. Click an options button, which pops up a dialog.
2. Set some checkboxes, radio buttons, etc...
3. Submit form (dialog seems to need it's own form)

Do you usually just save the inputs in a session, cookie, or do you have another way access your dialog controls from the main form?

Seems like I'm missing something basic, as it should be easy to set some options and use them on the rest of the page.

All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass data from one page/dialog to another see [Passing parameters between pages](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)